# What does it mean to take expectation over X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Given some expression, for example a quadratic form $\langle X, AY \rangle$, where both $X$ and $Y$ are $N(0,I_n)$ random vectors. What do we mean by 
$\mathbb{E}_X\left[\langle X, AY \rangle\right]$.

Do we mean to condition on $Y$ and average over $X$? 
How should one think about such an expression; is it conditional expectation or something completely different.

Also how does it relate to Fubini's, for example

$\mathbb{E}_Y\mathbb{E}_X\left[\langle X, AY \rangle\right]$

Is this actually changing the order of two conditional expectations?

This question primarily stems from notation used in High-Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershynin.

Comment: This is not standard notation, so you would have to look through your text for a definition. If I were to make an educated guess, I would assume it means integrating over the $X$ variable only. Specifically, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $\mu$ is the law of $X$, then my guess is $\mathbb E_X[\langle X,AY\rangle] :=\int \langle x,AY\rangle \mu(dx)$.